# How do I do mouse picking in OpenGL in Google NaCl?

Tags: opengl-es, google-nativeclient

The [NaCl Do's and Don'ts](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/3D-graphics) has this to say:

> Don’t read data from the GPU. Don’t call glReadPixels, as it is slow.

Traditionally, I do mouse picking through unprojection (inverse matrix and depth buffer reads). What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bullet Physics to do raycasting and picking. Look at the introductory tutorials on the bullet website then set up a debugDrawer following the tutorial at opengl-tutorial.org in the "picking with bullet" section.